# Famous-Angular with Meteor

Tags: meteor, famo.us, famous-angular

Is there a way to use Famous-Angular with Meteor.js?  I have tried to add the ngMeteor package with Famono and the bower package with famous-angular in the smart.json.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the famous-views. http://famous-views.meteor.com

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some work done for an older release of meteor. Check out
https://github.com/Splendsome/meteor-famous-angular

Answer (score 0):

Check out [angular-meteor](http://angularjs.meteor.com) a great integration between those two amazing frameworks

And look at this [boilerplate](https://github.com/hlandao/meteor-angular-famous-boilerplate) (very early WIP) that is using angular-meteor

Answer (score -2):

why would you want to? That's like asking "how to use meteor with SOAP?" - you don't need to.
meteor includes a much simpler to use reactive UI (blaze) that obviates angular. 
look at the famono package for meteor to get those two cooking together.

look beyond the buzzwords to figure out what you actually need to do.

Comment: Angular is not only about reacte ui, it's about project and code organization and the flexibility to scaffold everything in a very organized manner, plus DI, plus directives, plus ... plus ...